# sending ajax data in array and receiving back the data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i am taking the input from user and than showing the data and a button for confirmation after clicking the confirm button the data will be post to a php file but the data is in array i am handling that data with for each loop but it is giving me an error that invalid arguments supplied to for each loop i don't know why it is giving me an error.
here is html and ajax code.

```
<html>
 <head><title>my jquery</title>
 <script src="jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
 </head>
<body>

 <button id="button">clickme</button>
 Id:<input type="text" id="id" >
 Name:<input type="text" id="name">
 Message:<input type="text" id="message" >
 Destination:<input type="text" id="destination" >
 <button id="confirm" name="confirm">Confirm</button>
 <div id="d">
  <table id="t">
   <tr>
    <td>ID</td>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Message</td>
    <td>Destination</td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </div>

 <script type="text/javascript">
    var arr = new Array();
    $("#button").click(function(){
       var id=$("#id").val();
       var name=$("#name").val();
       var message=$("#message").val();
       var destination=$("#destination").val();

       arr.push({id:id, name:name, msg:message, dest:destination});
       for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
          //alert(arr.length);
          var row="<tr><td>"+ arr[i].id +"</td><td>"+ arr[i].name +"</td><td>"+ arr[i].msg +"</td><td>"+ arr[i].dest +"</td></tr>";
       }
       $("#t").append(row);
    });

    $("#confirm").click(function(){
       $.ajax({
          type:"POST",
          url:"ajax.php",
          data:"data="+JSON.stringify(arr),
          success: function(data){
             alert(data);
          }
       });
    });
 </script>
</body>
```

And the php code is here.
please someone tell me why the for each loop is not working.

```
 <?php
        if(isset($_POST['data'])){
    $yourdata = $_POST['data'];
    foreach($yourdata as $data){
        echo $data['id'];
    }
    var_dump($yourdata);
    $yourdatas = json_decode($yourdata);
    print_r($yourdata);
}
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
 data: {'yourdata':JSON.stringify(arr)},
```

instead of

```
 data:"data="+arr,
```

in your php page,

```
 <?php
    $yourdata = $_POST['yourdata'];
    $yourdatas = json_decode($yourdata);
    var_dump($yourdatas); 
 ?>
```

Comment: Maybe even data: "data=" + JSON.stringify(arr) (json_decode() should be used server-side to unserialize data)

Comment: may be but when I send data I get back an alert that look like that string(15)"[object,object]" I don't know why this string is coming in my alert

Comment: yup now the data is dumping but still the foreach loop is not working

Comment: can you apply the for each loop to this array

Comment: can you post the result array, it helps me to write foreach accordingly

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
data:{'data':JSON.stringify(arr)}
```

and in your php

```
$data=json_decode(filter_input(INPUT_POST, "data"));
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: my problem is with that foreach loop why the loop is not working when the data is an array

Comment: I am not encoding and I don't need to decode it if I am not encoding in json_encode

Comment: @Aitazaz Khan as my experience when we `stringify` the `array` the array becomes `json` string and we have to decode it in server side. The code given is working for me.

Comment: dear but I am not stringify the data as well I am sending only the array and in php file I am applying for each loop to the array

Comment: it give me an array of array to string conversion

Comment: Can you check what `is_array(arr)` returns

Comment: yeah for sure I am going to check it

Comment: nope but I wana fetch the specific data from the array

Comment: now every thing is working fine showing me the data but now I want to retrieve specific data from this array how can I do this

Comment: print_r is working var_dump is working but obiviously If I want to retrieve specific data I will use foreach loop

Comment: @Aitazaz Khan can you give your resultant array. Let me check